# SQL ERROR: [Npgsql] ErrorMessage: Backend sent unrecognized response type: F

Tags: sql, reserved-words

I am trying to execute the following sql:

```
INSERT INTO equity (cod_equity,name,cod_class_equity,isin,sedol,cod_country,cod_exchange,cod_currency,ticker_bbg,underlying_asset_conversion,cod_underlying_asset,mellon_name,cod_reporting_currency,cod_company,cod_country_domicile,cod_mask_asset) 
        VALUES ( '2207','C&A MODAS LTDA','9','BRCEABACNOR1',
                 'BKPHNH3','34', NULL,'21', 'CEAB3 BZ EQUITY',
                  NULL,NULL,'CEAB3','21','592','34',NULL
               )
```

ps: on the beginning, "name" is highlighted in red.

It results the following error:

[Npgsql] ErrorMessage:

> Backend sent unrecognized response type: F

Comment: Sovled. Could't found the delete question buttom.

Comment: Was it because `name` is a reserved word in some versions of SQL? You can answer your own question if you think it might help others with the same problem.